# can't understand strange construction in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, yaml

in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test
  - finish

.dev_branch: &dev_branch
  - dev

test:
 stage: test
 script: 
   - echo "test"

finish:
 stage: finish
 script: 
   - echo "finish"
```

what does it mean?

```
.dev_branch: &dev_branch
  - dev
```

dev_branch is the anchor?
what it do in this CI
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/), this is an **YAML Anchor**, it is used to define a snippet of code that you can call later by referencing it with `*`, in your case, whatever is inside `dev_branch` could be replicated with `*dev_branch`.

Gitlab has a [section on the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts) about using YAML Anchors inside CI/CD scripts.